# How do we merge 2 more pdf file into single page(A4) PDF using ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I want to merge 3 PDF files with size(210X99) into single page PDF file in A4 size (210X297) by using ghostscript (gswin32c.exe)

PDF may contain images or text any thing

**Input Pdfs:**

[image]

**Output PDF:**

[image]

Comment: +1 for adding comprehensive drawings to explain your goal :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this, using Ghostscript, and if the input files contain more than a single page there is no way at all to do it.

You would need to write a PostScript program which overrides the showpage performed by the PDF interpreter at the end of every page, and also translate the PostScript origin before every input PDF file in order to start the new page at an appropriate offset.

It can be done but there is no out of the box solution for this and some PostScript programming will be required.

Comment: oh ok fine, i do't know about gs, but i did my job with the help of iTextSharp, by using iText we can do.